# Hooking custom maven plugin with maven release plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins, maven-plugin

I have written one maven plugin which analyze some files and throw an error if it finds some predefined pattern in that file.

Now the issue is i want to hook up this maven plugin with maven release plugin, so that if user releases the project by giving command mvn release:prepare then only my plugin will come in picture.

But i am not able to hookup my plugin with mvn release plugin.

I tried by :

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <preparationGoals>check-pattern</preparationGoals>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

but it complains like :

```
Unknown lifecycle phase "check-pattern". 
You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>.

Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
```

And if i give in this manner:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                  <plugin-group-id>com.plugin.snapshot</plugin-group-id>
                  <plugin-artifact-id>snapshot-maven-plugin</plugin-artifact-id>
                  <plugin-version>0.0.1</plugin-version>
                   <goal> check-pattern </goal>
                    <preparationGoals>check-pattern</preparationGoals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

then it doesn't complain but aldo doesn't run my maven plugin.

Is there some way so that i can hookup mine plugin with maven release plugin?

Comment: You have to define an execution in the build life cycly as any othe r maven plugin. Or have you tried to do `your-maven-plugin:check-pattern` in preparationGoals ?

Comment: thanks, i got the solution, actually i didn't checked the maven suggestion: {You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>.}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with below configuration:

```
<configuration>
 <preparationGoals>com.plugin.snapshot:snapshot-maven-plugin:check-snapshot</preparationGoals>
</configuration>
```

Now when i am releasing my project the maven release prepare plugin is calling my plugin goal.